# Why does resharper suggests using readonly in fields that are not changed?

Tags: c#, resharper

to clarify the question, I'd like to add that I'm not asking why I should choose readonly over const or what are the benefits of readonly over const.

I'm asking why to make a field readonly just because it's not changed (at the moment).

for example:
if I'd write the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
      public int _i = 5;

      // Code that doesn't change the value of i:
      ...
}
```

Resharper will indicate that it can be made readonly.

Thanks

Comment: It's wrong advice, you made the field public.  If it would have suggested to use a property then it would have given you good advice.

Answer (score 29):

When it detects that you are not assigning to a variable except at initilization, it presumes that you don't want the variable to change.  Making the variable readonly (or const) will prevent you from assigning to the variable in the future.  Since this seems (by usage) to be the behavior you want, it makes the suggestion that you formalize it and derive the benefit of the protection.

Comment: Anyone care to comment on the downvote?  I'm always eager to learn when I may be wrong.

Comment: @Hogan: Saulius doesn't have any downvotes in his profile page.  Just another muppet having a bad day I guess.

Comment: @nobugz : wow good point -- I just assumed 'cuze we both got downvoted right after his comment.  doh!  Sorry @Saulius.

Answer (score 5):

I usually try to remember<sup>1</sup> to do what Resharper's trying to remind you to do.  If I have any fields that are immutable, I like to mark them with `readonly` to formalize that.  On many types, I do this will all the fields.  There are [benefits of immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=immutability) ([[2]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=immutable+objects)), and Resharper is trying to help you take advantage of them.

<sub><sup>1</sup> I personally don't use Resharper.  I have my reasons.</sub>

Comment: Help me understand: you try to remember to do what ReSharper's trying to remind you to do, but you don't personally use ReSharper. These two statements contradict each other.

Comment: I read his statement as "I agree to those rules R# gives you and try to follow them myself, although I don't use R# myself (anymore)".

Comment: @John Saunders: The "you" in my statement was literal, referring to the OP, not a substitute for the pronoun "one".  If Resharper were reminding **me** of something, then I wouldn't exactly have to try to remember it myself.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's pretty obvious, that a variable that's never changed should be either const or read-only. The question which one of these is better depends on the situation. Const variables are by definition constant - their values should *NEVER* change (e.g. `const int minutesInAnHour = 60;` looks like a good candidate). That's why the constant is a static member implicitly and it is initialized during compile time, i.e. the compiler might actually replace all the appearances of your constant with the literal value, though I'm not sure if any compiler actually does that.

Readonly, on the other hand, is a member variable whose value should not change, once initialized, meaning that it is not actually a constant, you can do something in the lines of `readonly DateTime time = DateTime.Now;`. This, of course, will not be a static member, in fact it will be a normal member just with the restriction that it can't be changed once assigned. The benefit of this vs. const is that if your const variable changes in some build, other dependad libraries may not know that - they can even have the constant value comppiled in - you'll have to rebuild everything.

And as for the question why resharper suggests readonly vs. const - I'm not sure, I'd guess that a readonly variable is less restrictive and it figures that that's what the developer probably wanted.

Comment: With regard to read-only-ness, there are two kinds of reference-type fields: those which may safely be assumed to always point to the same object, and those which may safely be made to point to different objects should the need arise.  Fields of the first type should be `readonly`, whether the objects to which they refer are mutable or immutable; fields of the second type should not be `readonly`, even if the class presently has no reason to change them after construction.  For example, if the first version of a class similar to `List<T>` requires the size to be specified in its constructor...

Comment: ...it might create an array within its constructor and use that same array forevermore.  If no code relies upon its continuing to that same array, a future version of the class might offer a `Resize` method that creates a new array, copies elements from the old one to the new one, and abandons the old one.  If any code anywhere does rely upon the class always using the same array, however, such a method wouldn't work.  The decision of whether or not to declare the array `readonly` would determine which path of future expansion would be permitted.

Answer (score 3):

Resharper is a tool, it can not see anything but the code you show it.  If you plan to change the code in the future Resharper has no way of knowing -- so it makes suggestions based on your current code.

Answer (score 3):

> Resharper will indicate that it can be made readonly.

To add to other answers, note that you can change the severity of this inspection in `ReSharper` | `Options` | `Code Inspection` | `Inspection Severity` | `Field can be made readonly`. I have it as 'Show as suggestion'; you can ask ReSharper to ignore this inspection entirely, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

When we use readonly and const in one compiled dll (let's call it 'source dll') which is used by another compiled dll (let's call it client's dll), then when we change const in source dll, we have to compile not only the source dll but also the client's dll, because const is set during compiling time. In turn, readonly is set during program's runtime, so when we change this value in source dll, then we have to only compile source dll, without compiling client's dll. I think this is one of the reasons that Resharper suggests readonly - because when it's changed, it will require less work. The second reason is, I think, what Saulius Valatka wrote, that const should be real 'constant' value, as for example 60 minutes in an hour and not value which seems to be constant, but eventually will change. So there are fewer real 'constant' values, than those which we think that will be 'constant', but eventually they change.